# :not(:disabled :read-only) v/s :not(:disabled, :read-only)

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Recently, I was working on a project and noticed something **i.e** chrome is treating `:not(:disabled :read-only)` and `:not(:disabled, :read-only)` equally *(didn't try any other browser)*. Now I have two questions :

1. Is there any difference **with** or **without comma** ?
2. <strike>I have read some where *(don't remember where)* that I should use `:not(:disabled):not(:read-only)` not `:not(:disabled, :read-only)` is there any difference in them also??</strike> **✅ SEE THE FIRST COMMENT**

For reference : I was using sass

**with comma**

```scss
input {
  &:not(:disabled, :ready-only) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

**without comma**

```scss
input {
  &:not(:disabled :ready-only) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

**Something Interesting**

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

input:not(:disabled), input:not(:read-only) {
  background-color: red;
}
input:not(:disabled, :read-only) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="">DISABLED</label>
  <input type="text" disabled />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="">READONLY</label>
  <input type="text" readonly />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="">DISABLED READONLY</label>
  <input type="text" disabled readonly />
</div>
```

Basically :

- `&:not(:disabled), &:not(:read-only)` **!=** `&:not(:disabled, :read-only)`
- `&:not(:disabled):not(:read-only)` **!=** `&:not(:disabled, :read-only)`

Comment: There used to be a difference. See [caniuse.com's entry for selector use in :not()](https://caniuse.com/css-not-sel-list).

Comment: `:not()` takes a selector list: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#selector-list

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks! What about the **1st** question ??

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: What do you mean by "used to be"? The level 4 usage hasn't changed, other than how specificity is calculated.

Comment: @BoltClock I mean what I said. Level 3 was different than level 4. At some point, browsers implemented level 3, yes? Then they implemented level 4? So, there used to be a way browsers interpreted commas (rejecting the selector in level 3), and it changed (accepting in level 4). From the link in my comment: "Selectors Level 3 only allowed :not() pseudo-class to accept a single simple selector, which the element must not match any of. Thus, :not(a, .b, [c]) or :not(a.b[c]) did not work. Selectors Level 4 allows :not() to accept a list of selectors."

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: Oh so you mean there was a difference between levels 3 and 4. I thought you meant the behavior used to be different depending on the comma (which is what the question was asking).

Answer (score 0):

So both are not technically working the same in your example please check below.

```css
input:not(:disabled, :read-only) {
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<input disabled />
<input readonly/>

<input disabled readonly/>
<input/>
```

```css
input:not(:disabled :read-only) {
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<input disabled />
<input readonly/>

<input disabled readonly/>
<input/>
```

the css with the space inbetween is an example of a [`complex selector`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/#aa-complex-selectors) which if we check with another type of example will demonstrate its usage!

```css
/* select all the p tags that are not having a parent of disabled! */
p:not(.disabled .read-only) {
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="disabled">
  <p class="read-only">
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    test
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Its like **with comma** both conditions should be true !? and **without comma** even if one condition is true. So basically **with comma** is like **&&** and **without comma** is like **||** ; like in javascript??  I AM STILL CONFUSED

Comment: @KunalTanwar with comma its like or condition, with space its like a standard css selector syntax, so in your example `input:not(:disabled :read-only)` it is input(with attribute read-only) whose parent is input(whose attribute is disabled)!

Comment: Maybe a clearer example using a <fieldset> which allows to match the `:disabled :readonly`: https://jsfiddle.net/j8s7aL5d/

Comment: @KunalTanwar does this answer solve your issue?